# Deploy ASP.NET MVC and Web API in the same solution, to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a Visual Studio solution with 3 layers (data, logic, service) and I also have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application consuming those layers, and a Web API to expose some functionality to the outside.

The question is how you handle the deployment of a such structure, because if you publish, ASP.NET MVC app and Web API separately, you will basically duplicate the business layers, so next time you will have to re-deploy again in 2 sites?

What I will have now in IIS: at the moment on my IIS folder:

```
* Web (folder)
    * Bin -> Data.dll, Logic.dll, Service.dll (duplicated)
```

and also

```
* Api (folder) 
    * Bin -> Data.dll, Logic.dll, Service.dll (duplicated)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

why dont just mvc app work only as a presentation layer and consume your api ?? by this buisness logic will not be repeatative as well as your future presentation layer could also consume the same apis ....

Comment: I've seen this solution in some website, but it's quite difficult to work properly with this kind of arquitecture, because i probably need to at least duplicate my entities in Mvc app because i cant reference to other layers

Comment: yeah i get it you might need a conman project with entities/model  for Shearing data ..

Answer (score 0):

Your service(web api) and application (Mvc) are basically 2 different applications. So you should deploy them separately. They will be served from 2 different domains (at least from different ports).

Whenever you make a change to service you only need to deploy the service. Same goes for the web application too.

But, what I feel will be enough for this project is, single MVC application (your web app), with WebApi controllers for exposing some endpoints (your service). So you'll only deploy one MVC application.

Comment: Thats true, but, if i have to change the core of my app any of the other 3 layers (data, logic, service), i will need to deploy those layers in 2 different folders, Web/Bin and Api/Bin, thats the big problem, basically they are 2 different apps but they consume the same layers

Comment: Then keep them separate. I don't see the confusing part.

Comment: I dont think that this will be the best option to have a shared folder for your core layers.

I will have at the moment on my IIS folder:

Web(Folder)
- Bin -> Data.dll, Logic.dll, Service.dll (Duplicated)

and also

Api(Folder)
- Bin -> Data.dll, Logic.dll, Service.dll (Duplicated)